# Render 'Buy Now' PayPal Smart Payment Button without branding

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-buttons

I have implemented PayPal on my PHP website. Everything is working fine but I want to show the PayPal button with a Buy Now and no 'PayPal' text

The documentation says to set `label:'buynow'` and `branding:false`

Ref link:- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-button/#label

```
<div id="paypal-button-container" style="width: 180px" class="btn submit"></div>

paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    label:   'buynow',
    layout:  'horizontal',
    color:   'blue',
    shape:   'rect',
    branding: false,
    height : 48
  },
  fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
  // onClick is called when the button is clicked
  onClick: function(data, actions) { ... },
  createOrder: function(data, actions) { ... }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

But the word 'PayPal' is still being displayed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You linked to the old/archived checkout.js SDK documentation

The `branding: false` parameter [is not supported](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/) by the latest Smart Payment Buttons SDK, which instead seems to be designed to be used more often in conjunction with the other payment methods like the Debit/Credit card embedded payment fields, Venmo, etc

So your unbranded option there would be to display the black "Debit/Credit Card" button that expands inline fields.

Comment: Well, the branding option is nothing doing here. If I remove that option the buy now button is still showing with Paypal. Can you please share the latest SDK link So that I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: As I mentioned, the branding option is not supported by the latest SDK. This means it will do nothing. The documentation is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/

Comment: Is there is any way to show the button label as "Buy Now" only i.e without Paypal? or like replace the CDN of Paypal with an older one!

Comment: With the Smart Payments Button SDK there is no way to remove the PayPal branding from that button. Instead, its unbranded option is to display a second black Debit/Credit card button that opens inline credit card fields. You can see a demo here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client